# How can I maximize the useability of my android app on as many devices as possible?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've been developing for the Galaxy Nexus device using android version 4.1. I've been relying on the action bar and the action bar drop down that you get by default when your action bar items don't fit.

While trying to investigate some ACRA crash reports, I'm trying to replicate user devices and noticed that some of them will not have the software back button or the action bar drop down menu which really diminishes the user experience.

Do I need to check for these features, and if they are not there provide and alternative means of navigation?

Also I noticed that my dialogs don't render as expected on some devices; the positioning is not correct....

Comment: For the action bar stuff, you may want to look into http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: @JeffS yeah man, I'm using that. So the action bar shows up but I don't get the drop down menu for some reason on some of these devices running older Androids....

Comment: That is normal. If devices have hardware menu button, you will not get menu dropdown. Users of those devices are used to using the menu button, so there should not be a useablity issue.

Comment: It seems then that I cannot guarantee that every emulator will also provide me with an interface that represents the associated hardware? I'm trying to emulate an HTC Evo from this page  and from the screens it looks like I should have the hardware buttons available which I don't... http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Comment: My advice is to go on Craigslist or something and buy a few devices from different Android eras and test BEFORE you deploy. Most are sub $100.